# Set Timezone for my datepicker in javascript

Tags: javascript, datepicker, timezone, bootstrap-datepicker

Here is my javascript for my datepicker, however it grabs the current timezone, i wan't it to always grab EST time. How would i achieve this?

```
function initdatetime() {
if ($('.dattim').length > 0) {
    $('.dattim').datetimepicker({
        format: 'd MM yyyy h:i:ss',
        autoclose: true,
        todayBtn: true,
        showMeridian: true
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Are you using the `datetimepicker` plugin from xdsoft? jQuery UI doesn't have a `datetimepicker` method, it only has `Datepicker`.

Comment: i recieved this website, was built with twitter bootstrap, sry dont know much other than that

Comment: I think you may have the wrong API, there is no Twitter bootstrap-datepicker method called `datetimepicker()`. It's `datepicker()`.

Comment: Look in your code. Where are you getting the datetimepicker code from?

Comment: changing datetimepicker to datepicker broke it, it was working fine just autofills current time of my browser. There is a js file called datetime.js and has jquery inside and that is referring to datetime picker, my bootstrap-datepicker.js isn't being used, i believe the coder is using a jquery one

Comment: I'm not saying to change it, I'm saying you need to understand where the code came from and get a copy of the API. That way you can see what methods and properties are available to you in order to get a result in Eastern Time.